# How do I insert a string element into a regular expression in Python?

Tags: python, regex

Assume I have a string element in python. How do I insert this list element into a regular expression using re.compile ?

What I have in mind is something like

```
mystring='esteban'
myregex=re.compile('[mystring] is (not)? very good at python')
```

The end goal is to do this inside a loop with mystring changing in each iteration. Therefore, I cannot just write it manually as

```
myregex=re.compile('esteban is (not)? very good at python')
```

Comment: myregex=re.compile('{} is (not)? very good at python'.format(mystring))

Comment: A regular expression is just a string, so it can be formated and concatenated like any other string. Just one advice use raw-strings `r'my regular expression'`, this avoids having to escape any special character sequences like `\n`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways

```
myregex=re.compile('{} is (not)? very good at python'.format(mystring))

myregex=re.compile('{s} is (not)? very good at python'.format(s=mystring))

myregex=re.compile('%s is (not)? very good at python'% (mystring))

myregex=re.compile('%(mystring)s is (not)? very good at python' % locals())

myregex=re.compile(mystring+' is (not)? very good at python')

myregex=re.compile(' '.join([mystring,'is (not)? very good at python']))
```

Like Stefano Sanfilippo Said,

The multiple ways are listed in decreasing order of reliability. The first is the **best** and the last is the **worst**

Comment: Of them, only the first one  should be used. The third one is acceptable but quite ugly, the second one is deprecated (might be ok if you are using an ancient version of Python) and the last one is just overkill.

Comment: @StefanoSanfilippo Yeah, just wanted to give the OP a choice. Edited it to make it better. Thanks

Comment: Don't forget `myregex=re.compile('{mystring} is (not)? very good at python'.format(mystring=mystring))`

Comment: @SethMMorton That variable name is too long, prefer using a shorter one. Anyway good one. Will add it to the list

Comment: @BhargavRao Agreed, it is too long, but it illustrates that dictionary-like substitution is possible.

Comment: @SethMMorton Edited it by making use of `s` as a variable, short and sweet

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable name

```
>>> mystring='esteban'
>>> myregex=re.compile(mystring+'is (not)? very good at python')
>>> myregex.pattern
'estebanis (not)? very good at python'
```

**OR**

```
>>> myregex=re.compile('%s is (not)? very good at python' %mystring)
>>> myregex.pattern
'esteban is (not)? very good at python'
```